# How to get an input value using "refs" in react-bootstrap form?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a form that appears in modal. So when user input a value, that value is stored in local storage. Here's a picture that help's you to understand what I mean:
[image]
Here is the code of the form:

```
function FieldGroup({id, label, help, ...props}) {
    return (
        <ReactBootstrap.FormGroup controlId={id}>
            <ReactBootstrap.ControlLabel>{label}</ReactBootstrap.ControlLabel>
            <ReactBootstrap.FormControl {...props} />
            {help && <ReactBootstrap.HelpBlock>{help}</ReactBootstrap.HelpBlock>}
        </ReactBootstrap.FormGroup>
    );
}

const formInstance = (
    <form>
        <FieldGroup
            id="formControlsText"
            type="text"
            label="Text"
            placeholder="Recipe Name"
            inputRef={ref => { this.input = ref; }}
        />
        <ReactBootstrap.FormGroup controlId="formControlsTextarea">
            <ReactBootstrap.ControlLabel>Ingredients</ReactBootstrap.ControlLabel>
            <ReactBootstrap.FormControl componentClass="textarea" placeholder="Enter Ingredients" />
        </ReactBootstrap.FormGroup>
    </form>
);
```

As I've read in bootstrap React tutorial, I should add
`<FormControl inputRef={ref => { this.input = ref; }} />`  to the FormControl props. But after adding it I get an error when modal form is invoked:

`[image]

Answer (score 34):

I just made this issue. My code:

```
<FormControl
    componentClass="input"
    placeholder="Enter recipe title"
    inputRef={(ref) => {this.input = ref}}
    defaultValue={title}/>
</FormGroup>
```

And then you can get the value from `<FormControl>` in some handler like this:

```
console.log(this.input.value);
```

Details can be found in my repo: https://github.com/kerf007/recipebook

Comment: `Warning: React (18) does not recognize the \`inputRef\` prop on a DOM element.`

Answer (score 10):

I have same problem with you, and this is my solution

```
const FieldGroup = ({id, label, help, inputRef, ...props}) =>
  <FormGroup controlId={id}>
    <ControlLabel>{label}</ControlLabel>
    <FormControl {...props} inputRef={inputRef}/>
    {help && <HelpBlock>{help}</HelpBlock>}
  </FormGroup>
```

and my form

```
<form>
    <FieldGroup
        id="bookName"
        type="text"
        label="Name"
        placeholder="Enter name..."
        inputRef = {(input) => this.inputName = input }
     />
    <FieldGroup
        id="bookAuthor"
        label="Author"
        type="text"
        placeholder="author 's name..."
        inputRef={(input) => this.inputAuthor = input}
     />
</form>
```

then you can get book 's name and author 's name value by:

```
this.inputName.value and this.inputAuthor.value
```

Answer (score 6):

This issue (or more like a change in the way it works) is related to React-Bootstrap. The way you're doing it won't work anymore.

The `<FormControl>` component directly renders the  or other specified component. If you need to access the value of an uncontrolled `<FormControl>`, **attach a ref to it as you would with an uncontrolled input, then call `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(ref)` to get the DOM node**. You can then interact with that node as you would with any other uncontrolled input.

Here's an example:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var FormControl = require('react-bootstrap').FormControl;

React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (<FormControl ref="formControl" />);
  },
  getFormControlNode: function() {
    // Get the underlying <input> DOM element
    return ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.formControl);
  }
});
```

As soon as you get the DOM element, you will be able to retrieve the value: `this.getFormControlNode().value` or do anything else that you want.

PS: Here's a [related github issue](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/1850) on this topic.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me, using https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

```
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.email = React.createRef();
    }

submit() {
        var email = this.email.current.value;
        console.log(email);
}
render() {
   return (
            <Form>
            <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Your email" ref={this.email} />
            <Button variant="primary" onClick={()=>this.submit()}>Send</Button>
            </Form>
           );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what it suggests to use is **the ref callback attribute**, so just change `inputRef` to `ref`.

FYI: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: It doesn't change anything, the same error. I think the problem is that       **" You may not use the ref attribute on functional components because they don't have instances."**

Comment: You can use the `ref` attribute on **functional stateless components**: https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-ref-attribute-dom-node/

Answer (score 0):

Hello this solution worked for me!

```
<Form
  noValidate
  validated={validated}
  onSubmit={(e) => this.handleSubmit(e)}
  style={{ width: '100%' }}
>
  <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
   <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
   <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Enter email" inputRef={(ref) => { this.email = ref }} required />
   <Form.Text className="text-muted"> Well never share your email with anyone else.
   </Form.Text>
  </Form.Group>
</Form>

handleSubmit(event) {
    console.log(event.target.elements.formBasicPassword.value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found how to get the `ref` from React-Bootstrap `<Form/>`.

```
 import React, {createRef} from 'react'  

    interface definedProps {} 
    interface definedState {
                  myRef: Object //I didn't found the more accurate type
              } 
    export default class SomeClass extends React.Component<definedProps,definedState> {
        state = {
            myRef: React.createRef<Form<any>>() //That's it!
        }

    const handleClose = () => {
        console.log('this.state.myRef: ', this.state.myRef); //Here we can take data from Form
        debugger; //todo: remove
    }

        render() {

            return (
                <div>
                     <Form ref={this.state.myRef}> { /*Here we're connecting the form's ref to State*/}
                        <Form.Group controlId='formName'>
                            <Form.Control
                                type='text'
                                placeholder='Enter Name'
                            />
                        </Form.Group>
                          ...
                        <Button
                            variant='primary'
                            onClick={handleClose}
                            >
                            Save Changes
                        </Button>
                        </Form>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you're using 'standard' <form/>, not <From/> React-Bootstrap , then value of myRef in the state should be initialized like this:  myRef: React.createRef<HTMLFormElement>()