# Pass form.control input with default value using ref to parent component in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What should be the best approach to pass form.control's input with defaultValue(I needed to display what to edit) that has been edited. I was using refs(following one of the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41085220/how-to-get-an-input-value-using-refs-in-react-bootstrap-form)) but it only works on self component. Tried to implement to Child to Parent but didn't work. Snippet of essential codes below:

Child.js

```
<Form.Control 
ref={this.props.categoryNewValue} 
defaultValue={this.props.categoryValue} 
onChange={this.props.handleAssetChange}/>
```

Parent.js

```
class App extends Component{   
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
            this.state = {
                assetItems:[],
                assetItemID:"",
                assetItemsToEdit:[],
                categoryItems:[]  
            }
            this.categoryNewValue = React.createRef();           
    }

handleAssetChange=(event)=>{
        this.setState({
            categoryNewValue: this.categoryNewValue.current.value
        })
        console.log(this.categoryNewValue)
    }

render(){
        return(
            <Router>               
                 <Route path='/Assets'>                       
                        <ViewAssets categoryNewValue={this.state.categoryNewValue}
                                    handleAssetChange={this.handleAssetChange}
                        />                                        
                    </Route>
            </Router>
        )
    }    
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that data always flows downwards from your logical units in the parent to the DOM nodes. Why not just pass the parent state to the child through props?

Parent.js (render function):

```
<ViewAssets pstate={this.state} />
```

I don't see any of the logic you used to setup and focus the refs on your child elements, but if you still want to see what that model would look like I recommend this [guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FXa9mMTKOu8) and the [react docs on forwarding refs](https://5b05c94e0733d530fd1fafe0--reactjs.netlify.com/docs/forwarding-refs.html).

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I think it is what on my current Parent code already 
`<ViewAssets categoryNewValue={this.state.categoryNewValue}
                     handleAssetChange={this.handleAssetChange}/>`
or is it not the same to what you are guiding me. Please enlighten me.

Comment: No problem, when you send the state down to the child element you're no longer restricted to calling handleAssetChange() from the parent component. If you move the method to the child component and target the state sent through from props, you no longer need to use backrefs.

Comment: Thank you for your looking into this. I was able to accomplish my question by not using ref and changing `categoryNewValue: this.categoryNewValue.current.value` to  `[event.target.name]: event.target.value`

Comment: Fantastic, coming back to this thread helped me understand some key concepts in react.